# Mongo Query is success but updated record is zero

Tags: mongodb

The following query works fine

```
db.employee.update(
    {_id: ObjectId("57da8822059a7f847ccc4f68"), fileAccessKey: "Test/Emp (1-100)/.*"},
    { $set: { isWorking: true}},
    true,
    true
);
```

Matches found but isWorking is not updated

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

Any suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: The [signature of `update`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update) is as follows `db.collection.update(<query>, <update>, <option>)`. Why are you passing `true`?

Comment: even if i corrected the syntax, observes the same behavior. it seems SQL injection getting failed since "(" should be injected

Comment: any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure that it is not updated? If the value of `isWorking` is already `true` then you will see a match but no modification ...

Comment: ( are needs to be escaped in regex